# Laravel: redirect to index view does not fire method

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-4

I'm creating a demo project. At the moment I'm building the basics for a users component. I created a resourceful route in my routes file, generated a UsersController via artisan, and started filling in the code.

In my `UsersController` I have a simple `index` method:

```
public function index()
{
     $users = User::all();
     return View::make('users.index')->with('users',  $users);
}
```

A `create` method for the new user form:

```
public function create()
{
    return View::make('users.create');
}
```

And a `store` method for the new user form submission:

```
public function store()
{
    $user = new User;
    $user->username  = Input::get('username');
    $user->email     = Input::get('email');
    $user->nameFirst = Input::get('nameFirst');
    $user->nameLast  = Input::get('nameLast');
    $user->password  = Input::get('password');
    $user->save();

    Redirect::route('users.index');
}
```

Right now, all of these work individually. The index method grabs all of the users and displays them correctly in my `views/users/index.blade.php` view, the new user form generates correctly, and when I submit the form it fires the `store` method and writes the user data to the database.

The problem I'm having is that when I try to redirect back to the index view using `Redirect::route('users.index');` I get a blank browser window. My url shows as expected, `http://localhost:8001/users`, but I get a completely blank window:
[image]

I read through the docs and it looks like I'm using the redirect route correctly. Can anyone help figure out what's going wrong?

I should also add that it doesn't seem like the redirect works regardless of which route I point it to. No matter which one of the route name I use I still get  blank browser window.

EDIT: Here are my views:

Here's the `views/users/index.blade.php` file:

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('title')
User List
@stop

@section('content')
    <table>
      <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Username</th>
             <th>First</th> 
             <th>Last</th>
             <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      @foreach($users as $user)
          <tr>
              <td>{{ link_to("/users/{$user->username}", $user->username) }}</td>
              <td>{{ $user->nameLast }}</td>
              <td>{{ $user->nameFirst }}</td>
              <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
          </tr>
      @endforeach        
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
        {{ HTML::linkAction('users.create', "Create User") }}
    </div>

@stop
```

Here's the `views/users/create.blade.php` file:

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
    <h1>Create a New User</h1>
    {{ @Form::open(['route' => 'users.store']) }}
        <div>
            {{ Form::label('nameFirst', "First Name") }}
            {{ Form::text('nameFirst') }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ Form::label('nameLast', "Last Name") }}
            {{ Form::text('nameLast') }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ Form::label('username', "Username") }}
            {{ Form::text('username') }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ Form::label('email', "Email") }}
            {{ Form::text('email') }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ Form::label('password', "Password") }}
            {{ Form::password('password') }}
        </div>

        {{ Form::submit('Create User') }}
    {{ @Form::close() }}

@stop
```

The `routes.php` file:

```
    <?php

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return "home";
});

Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

And the routes per `php artisan routes`:

```
+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+-------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                         | Name          | Action                  | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+-------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET|HEAD /                  |               | Closure                 |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD users              | users.index   | UsersController@index   |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD users/create       | users.create  | UsersController@create  |                |               |
|        | POST users                  | users.store   | UsersController@store   |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD users/{users}      | users.show    | UsersController@show    |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD users/{users}/edit | users.edit    | UsersController@edit    |                |               |
|        | PUT users/{users}           | users.update  | UsersController@update  |                |               |
|        | PATCH users/{users}         |               | UsersController@update  |                |               |
|        | DELETE users/{users}        | users.destroy | UsersController@destroy |                |               |
+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+-------------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try it, it work for me

```
public function store()
{
   ...
   return Redirect::to('users');
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it gives the same result, a blank page. If I click in the address bar and hit enter the index page loads and shows all of the users.

Comment: Can you show your `index.blade.php`? And check your index.blade.php path is `app/views/users/index.php`? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I'll add it to the original post as an edit in just a sec.

Comment: And could you check this path's folder permission is 755 => `app/storage`. I make this folder permission is 755 and sub folder.

Comment: Yep, it's 755 `[chriss-mbp:app]: ls -l | grep storage
drwxr-xr-x   8 cschmitz  staff   272 May 18 12:32 storage`

Comment: This is my route, `Route::resource('account', 'AccountController');`, I use another controller name.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53924/discussion-between-lll-and-chris-schmitz)

Answer (score 0):

The important thing here is using the `return` before the redirect.

```
return redirect('/whatever-path/');
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for the input! It would not hurt if you could offer a bit more context for your answer. A nice introduction to amazing answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer